# How to group same values in a parent array?

Tags: php, laravel

I want to create story for my ios app, I am trying to get useful json response for it. I want to show same user stories in a group inside of that user`s array.

Current JSON RESULT;

```
{
"current_page": 1,
"data": [
{
"id": 3,
"name": "Muhammed Ali Yüce",
"username": "ali",
"avatar": "1544128196.png",
"stories": {
"id": 3,
"user_id": 3,
"image": "1550228567.jpg",
"created_at": "2019-02-15 11:02:47",
"updated_at": "2019-02-15 11:02:47"
}
},
{
"id": 2,
"name": "Ömer Faruk YÜCE",
"username": "omer",
"avatar": "1544128227.png",
"stories": {
"id": 2,
"user_id": 2,
"image": "1550228407.jpg",
"created_at": "2019-02-15 11:00:08",
"updated_at": "2019-02-15 11:00:08"
}
},
{
"id": 2,
"name": "Ömer Faruk YÜCE",
"username": "omer",
"avatar": "1544128227.png",
"stories": {
"id": 1,
"user_id": 2,
"image": "1550072626.jpg",
"created_at": "2019-02-13 15:43:47",
"updated_at": "2019-02-13 15:43:47"
}
}
],
"first_page_url": "/?page=1",
"from": 1,
"last_page": 1,
"last_page_url": "/?page=1",
"next_page_url": null,
"path": "/",
"per_page": 10,
"prev_page_url": null,
"to": 3,
"total": 3
}
```

I did tried groupBy func for it but it was not what I excepted.

I want to get result like this;

```
{
"id": 3,
"name": "Muhammed Ali Yüce",
"username": "ali",
"avatar": "1544128196.png",
"stories": [
{
"id": 2,
"user_id": 3,
"image": "1550228567.jpg",
"created_at": "2019-02-15 11:02:47",
"updated_at": "2019-02-15 11:02:47"
},
{
"id": 3,
"user_id": 3,
"image": "1550228567.jpg",
"created_at": "2019-02-15 11:02:47",
"updated_at": "2019-02-15 11:02:47"
}
]
```

StoryController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Story;
use App\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Image;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator;

class StoryController extends Controller
{

  public function index(Request $request){

    $userId = $request->id;

    $followsArr = [$userId];
    $follows = DB::table('follows')->whereNotIn('ismuted', [1])->where('follower', $userId)->get();

    foreach ($follows as $follow) {
      $friend = $follow->following;
      $followsArr[] = $friend;
    }

    $itemCollection = collect($followsArr);

      $stories = [];

      Story::whereIn('user_id', $itemCollection)
      ->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')
      ->get()->each(function ($story) use (&$stories){

        $user = User::where('id', $story->user_id)->first();

        $stories[] =
          ['id' => $user->id]
        + ['name' => $user->name]
        + ['username' => $user->username]
        + ['avatar' => $user->avatar]
        + ['stories' => $story->toArray()];

      });


      // Get current page form url e.x. &page=1
              $currentPage = LengthAwarePaginator::resolveCurrentPage();

              // Create a new Laravel collection from the array data
              $itemCollection = collect($stories);

              // Define how many items we want to be visible in each page
              $perPage = 10;

              // Slice the collection to get the items to display in current page
              $currentPageItems = $itemCollection->slice(($currentPage * $perPage) - $perPage, $perPage)->all();

              // Create our paginator and pass it to the view
              $paginatedItems= new LengthAwarePaginator($currentPageItems , count($itemCollection), $perPage);


      return response()->json($paginatedItems);

  }
```

I hope you will understand what I mean, Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Please don't add text as images. Include the expected result in your question as text as well.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson thanks for notice, I thought it will be more readable So I added it. Im editing it now, thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume you have `User.php` and `Story.php` Models

In User.php

```
public function stories()
{
   return $this->hasMany(Story::class);
}
```

You can load story along with user. something like that

```
$user = User::where('id', $story->user_id)->with('stories')->first(); //Eager Load

or 

$user = User::where('id', $story->user_id)->first();
$user->load('stories'); //Lazy Eager Load
```

Please read more about [Laravel Eloquent: Relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships)

Comment: thanks ! it`s working as what I excepted but there is one more problem too. For example; If user has two stories, its showing twice same result in array, how can I show only an item ?

Comment: I don't things so it's showing twice same results. please check your records once.  or share your logic and tables (User, Story)